# How to change the elevation/height of a map marker on street view?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Is it possible to change the elevation (or height?) of a marker on a street view map. E.g if I want it to sit at eye height instead of sitting on the floor like the Facebook icon is in my demo.

I have a demo here [DEMO](http://codepen.io/ifusion/pen/obQrJr?editors=1010)

```
  function initialize() {

    google.maps.streetViewViewer = 'photosphere'; // use the new beta viewer
    var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
      document.getElementById('pano'), {
        position: {lat: -43.5376185, lng: 172.6424808},
        pov: {heading: 251.58, pitch: 0, zoom: 0.5},
        linksControl: true,
        panControl: true,
        enableCloseButton: true
    });

    var facebookMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: -43.5376324, lng: 172.6424267},
        map: panorama,
        icon: {
            url: '../images/fb-icon.png',
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 1)
        },
        title: 'Facebook Marker',
    });

    var youtubeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: -43.5375100, lng: 172.6422784},
        map: panorama,
        icon: '../images/youtube-icon.png',
        title: 'Youtube Marker'
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: @MrUpsidown ah yes I see. Bummer looks like I'm out of luck for the time being..

Comment: Yup... basically, if the marker is within a very short distance, it will appear on the ground level, and the further you walk away from it, the higher it will raise above the "horizon" if I can say so... being able to place it at a specific *altitude* would kind of break that.

Comment: @MrUpsidown - Any idea how google are doing it? http://i.stack.imgur.com/10vAA.jpg - Tour is here: http://tinyurl.com/jy3wcrn

Comment: I believe this was done with [Google Tour Builder](https://tourbuilder.withgoogle.com/). Yet another product from Google. But sorry I don't know much about it...